# css centering issue on middle column

Tags: html, css

I have got an issue in a header where I want the middle element to stay centered between the two flash end pieces.   I put the middle element after the right div in the html, thought I specified the css right, but when I STRETCH the page to the right, the middle element does not move/stay centered.  Are you able to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Some code to look at would be nice!

Comment: Throw in a picture and some code would be better.

Comment: put the code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can all debug together

Comment: please add some code to look at..or put it at <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">Jsfiddle</a>..that way you will get better responses

Comment: @Macros figured it out (below).  Per adding in code, I figured rather than copying tons stuff to jsfiddle, folks could simply use Firebug or Chrome Debug Tools to see the elements that are getting applied directly on the page, for the real site.   Perhaps you can shed light on the question I asked Macros below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the code on the page you supplied, you need to remove the float:left from the headerCenter div

Comment: thanks, that did it.  Can you help me understand the html/css dynamics of a center column better?  If I don't float it, why will it go to the right of the first header element?

Comment: By floating to the left (or right) you are effectively removing the element from the normal block layout flow.  In the markup the center column appears after the righthand div however you have then specified to push the right hand div as far right as possible (float:right) and the center div will fill the space left.  You can see that the center div is overlapped by the righthand one using firebug

Comment: Thanks.  Is this the "right" (normal) way to do a center div/column, or is there a more straight forward way?